# PHP Undefined Index/ How do I 'define' html array

Tags: php, arrays, forms

Hi quick question on PHP which I'm still learning why is $html[$firstname] in code below coming up as undefined index in server error logs........
Quick answer would be awesome......

Hi here's all the code for clarity, let me know if the code for the PDO is good enough and that there is no need for escaping, I'm guessing that html entities isn't required until I'm outputting data from the database via php to the browser.

```
<?php

$firstname = "";
$lastname = "";
$username = "";
$email = "";
$password = "";
$confirm_password = "";
$_POST['firstname'] = $firstname;
$_POST['lastname'] = $lastname;
$_POST['username'] = $username;
$_POST['email'] = $email;
$_POST['password'] = $password;
$_POST['confirm_password'] = $confirm_password;
$clean =  array();
if(ctype_alnum($firstname)){
  $clean[$firstname] = $firstname;
};
if(ctype_alnum($lastname)){
  $clean[$lastname] = $lastname;
};
if(ctype_alnum($username)){
  $clean[$username] = $username;
};

if(isset($email)){
  filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
};
//initialize an array for escaped data
$html = array();
//escape the filtered data
$html[$firstname] = htmlentities($clean[$firstname], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$html[$lastname] = htmlentities($clean[$lastname], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$html[$username] = htmlentities($clean[$username], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$html[$email] = htmlentities($email, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$html[$password] = htmlentities($password, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$html[$confirm_password] = htmlentities($confirm_password, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
//
//write function to generate random salt for every password, + bcrypt allpasswords, then store in db


$salt = substr(str_replace('+', '.', base64_encode(pack('N4', mt_rand(),  mt_rand(), mt_rand(), mt_rand()))), 0, 22);
$hash = crypt($html[$password], '$2a$10$'.$salt.'$');


$currentPassword = '$2a$15$Ku2hb./9aA71tPo/E015h.LsNjXrZe8pyRwXOCpSnGb0nPZuxeZP2';
$checkPassword = $password;
if(crypt($checkPassword, $currentPassword) === $currentPassword){
    echo 'You are in!';
}else{
    echo 'You entered the wrong password';
}

// store everything in the database execute prepare, then send back the email verification, do not send
//new password to email, and don't send forgotten password to email, just get them to remember it and click the link'
//connect to the database
$user = "*****";
$dbpassword = "****";
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=_virtualpiersclose', $user, $dbpassword);
$statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, username, email, password)
    VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :username, :email, :password)");
$statement->bindParam(':firstname', $html[$firstname]);
$statement->bindParam(':lastname', $html[$lastname]);
$statement->bindParam(':username', $html[$username]);
$statement->bindParam(':email', $html[$email]);
$statement->bindParam(':password',$html[$password]);

$statement->execute();

$db = NULL;

?>
```

Comment: The code you posted does not suggest that `$html[$firstname]` is ever used undefined. Are you sure this is the relevant code? PHP usually acompanies such messages with a line number. Are you sure the error message is about `$html[$firstname]`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplih? Are you trying to escape/sanitize your user input? because if you are you are going about it the wrong way

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code.

Comment: Hi yeah I was researching santization last night, and discovered the my_sql_real_escape_string is deprecated, so I have decided to use PDO prepared statements principally to avoid sql injection, is this enough for escaping with using prepare/bindParam/execute or should there be an added layer of escaping. I figured that using html entities would prevent any XSS getting in, then potentially getting out via the database also........

Comment: @AntPower it is mysql_real_escape_string() and yes if you use PDO (and use it correctly) you will be fine. However currently in your script there is no database connection so we cannot help you with that.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you wanted was:

```
$html['firstname']
```

Having said that, your code is a little crazy and doesn't make much sense.  Here are some access patterns:

```
$ar = array(
    'firstname' => 'Joe',
    'hello' => 'Hi there!'
);

$n = 'firstname';  // assign the string 'firstname' to $n
$x = $ar['firstname'];  // $x becomes 'Joe'
$x = $ar[$n]; // also $x becomes 'Joe', because $n is 'firstname'
$x = $ar[$firstname]; // doesn't return anything, because the variable $firstname is not assigned.  Will trigger a warning, too.
$firstname = 'hello'; // assign 'hello' to $firstname
$x = $ar[$firstname]; // $x becomes 'Hi there!'
$ar['hello'] = 'Good Bye.'; // Change $ar['hello']
$ar[$firstname] = 'So long!'; // Also changes $ar['hello']
```

You also have your assignment statement backwards.  The variable on the left-hand side of the equals sign receives the value from the right-hand side.  I think you wanted the contents of `$_POST['firstname']` to be saved in the variable `$firstname`.  Here's a few lines that probably need to be fixed:

```
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
// ... etc ...
if(ctype_alnum($firstname)){
    $clean['firstname'] = $firstname;
};
```

Comment: But `$html['firstname']` is never used in a manner that would provoke a message about an undefined index.

Comment: `$firstname` is an empty string.  The statement `$html['']` will return the warning about undefined index.

Comment: No, it won't. The empty string is a perfectly legal array index.

Comment: True, but if the variable `$html['']` was never set then it is an invalid index.  All of this is beside the point anyway: the OP's code is a shambles because he's apparently new to PHP and needs a little help.  I still think he has his basic array access patterns wrong.

Comment: Writing to an array at an undefined index automatically creates that index entry. Morover writing to `$array[$index]` if `$array` is undefined automatically creates an array `$array` and the appropriate array entry. And the code from the question does not read from `$html['']`.

Comment: Well, actually now it does. I'm still confused because of the messed up indentation, but Ant Power does not seem to be willing to fix that.

Comment: *sigh* You have to follow his code more closely.  `ctype_alnum($firstname)` returns `false`, so `clean['']` is never set.  And he should be getting Notices when `$html[$firstname]` is assigned, because `htmlentities($clean[''], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')` will totally fail due to the index not existing.  Like I said, he needs to fix his understanding of how to access arrays before the rest of this becomes fixable.

Comment: Also I took on board and understood what you were saying about access patterns, thank you for the lesson.........